# MVC repository and interface returning Json

Tags: json, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I'm new at MVC and can't get this to work.  I basically have a Users class, a UserRepository, and a IUser interface.

This is my code:

```
public class Users
{

public string UserName { get; set; }
public string Department { get; set; }
public string UserType { get; set; }


}

 public class UsersRepository : TimeAttendanceMVC.Models.IUsers
{

    public Users Return_UserName_Dept()
    {
        Users U = new Users();
        List<Users> LoggedInUser = new List<Users>();

        U.UserName = "TestUser";
        U.Department = "Finance";
        U.UserType = "Administrator";

        LoggedInUser.Add(U);

        //string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(LoggedInUser, Formatting.Indented);
        //return json;

        return Json(LoggedInUser.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }


}

namespace TimeAttendanceMVC.Models
{
  public  class IUsers
    {
      List<Users> Return_UserName_Dept();

    }
}
```

There are a few errors that I get.  In UsersRepository.cs where i'm returning Json, the error says that "The name Json does not exist in the current context".  The error from IUsers.cs is that "Return_UserName_Dept() must declare a body because it is not marked abstract...".

Can anybody please help me with this.  I just don't know how this is supposed to work and i'm trying to learn MVC by working on this application.  It's actually the FullCalendar application found here -  [link to FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).  I'm trying to turn it into an MVC application.

---

EDIT:

Maybe I need to do this:

public JsonResult Return_UserName_Dept()

instead of public Users Return_UserName_Dept()

Comment: I'm not familar with Json but it looks like you meant `return new Json(...` ?, i.e. you left out the new keyword?

Comment: Hi, it actually should be return `Json(...)` as it's a method, it's just that this method is not available where he's calling it. Should be called from inside a `JsonResult` method in the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing this on your controller in some method which returns a json action (jsonresult). The repository should be returning your data only and all the operations you need to do, whether you're converting data to json or any other logic should happen at the controller or at some helper class which would be called by the controller..

Edit:

In order to have a method which returns a JsonResult, you need to have a reference to System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult and since the repository is usually at the model, you won't have this reference.. another thing is that you might be breaking your design the logic should be available at the controller for what you want

Edit 2:

The code below is from an old post you can see [here](http://shashankshetty.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/using-jsonresult-with-jquery-in-aspnet-mvc/). Note how the action `PopulateDetails` gets the user object from the repository and *that's all* the repository does.. the actual logic is happening inside this method, such as populate the rest of the `UserModel` class, and *then* it returns the JsonResult:

```
public JsonResult PopulateDetails(UserModel model)
{
    UserResultModel userResultModel = new UserResultModel();
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.UserId))
    {
        userResultModel.Message = "UserId can not be blank";
        return Json(userResultModel);
    }

    User user = _userRepository.GetUser(model.UserId);

    if (user == null)
    {
        userResultModel.Message = String.Format("No UserId found for {0}", model.UserId);
        return Json(userResultModel);
    }

    userResultModel.LastName = user.LastName;
    userResultModel.FirstName = user.FirstName;
    userResultModel.Message = String.Empty; //success message is empty in this case

    return Json(userResultModel);
}
```

Comment: I thought in MVC the controller only received the data from the Model.  I didn't think it was a good idea to have the controller do any of the work except to take the data and pass it to my view.

Comment: Oh I see.  I tried to add the reference in my repository and got an error.  You're saying to add it in the controller.

Comment: Yes, the controller receives data from the model and that's it.. that's all the model should do, handle the data.. All the logic *should* happen at the controller.. the only logic happening at the model should be related to retrieve data from the source and populate your model objects.. the controller gets the data from the model and does the operations to convert or whatever you need.. and it can use other objects to segregate the logic according to what you need to do.

Comment: what I'm saying is that you should have your controller call the repository and get the model and then return as a jsonresult; the repository shouldn't return the json (it doesn't make sense to me imho).

Comment: Hmmm...ok.  Maybe i just misunderstood this whole MVC pattern.  I will try to return Json at the controller level.  Thank you.